# Simple Form - Translating options of a input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, simple-form

I'm trying to use the i18n feature of simple form, which works great in most cases.

My only problem is, that in one case I want to use numbers as option values, so I can not  simply create a symbol like in the other cases. Right now, I'm using this solution:

```
f.input :adm, :as => :select, :collection => [[:adm11 ,"11"], 
      [:adm00, "00"], [:adm06, "06"], [:adm99, "99"]]
```

Can I somehow make simple_form look up adm11 and so on in the usual way, so I can keep a sensible structure in my translation file?

I know I could do it with standard ruby i18n, but I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f.input :adm,
    :collection => [[:adm11 ,"11"], [:adm00, "00"], [:adm06, "06"],
                   [:adm99, "99"]],
    :label_method => lambda { |el| t "define.i18n.keys.here.#{el.first}" }
```

Comment: @panmari The age of miracles is past :)

Comment: I'll be using this method then

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do it because of this line in `SimpleForm`:

```
collection_translated = translate_collection if collection_classes == [Symbol]
```

So it means that `SimpleForm` translates options if it's array of symbols. See discussion here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/302

Comment: And how can I make simple_form translate arrays, like in my case?

Comment: You can write helper for your case or just use Nash Bridges method.